# MyBatis / Play 2.0

Tags: ibatis, mybatis, playframework-2.0

is anyone already using myBatis with play 2.0?

Where is a good entry-point to initialize myBatis and read the config-file?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a complete example here: http://www.fdmtech.org/2012/03/a-better-example-of-play-framework-2-0-with-mybatis-for-scala-beta/

The source code is at github too: https://github.com/mnesarco/play2-mybatis-scala-better-sample